# Xcode crashes when I try to change the build version in the target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

## Hello, my xcode crashes when I try to change the build version in the target or add new capabilities to the target

I am using cocoa pods dependencies 
mapbox and moya 
I already recreated the project, added new files and crashed again 
Min version IOS 15 
Using SwiftUI 
Please tell me what could be the problem

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [70735]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.4.1 (20504)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-20504000000000000~2 (13F100)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       849405240
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2022-08-02 01:33:29.0104 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y910)
Anonymous UUID:        26D63ACB-658A-6CE0-1948-1A30209E23FB

Sleep/Wake UUID:       99B7552F-2B7B-4BF1-BEA3-9DC37E74F959

Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3344 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Application Specific Signatures:
0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81606300e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8160991ff pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff815fe4d24 abort + 123
3   IDEKit                                 0x1116ec69d +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1216
4   IDEKit                                 0x1116ecba8 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1075
5   DVTFoundation                          0x10e62624e _DVTAssertionHandler + 464
6   DVTFoundation                          0x10e62645a _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 306
7   DVTFoundation                          0x10e3ce9e9 -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable _setLiteralValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:wantsCheckForDVTMacroExpansionConformance:] + 515
8   DVTFoundation                          0x10e3ce7e4 -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable setLiteralValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:] + 23
9   DVTFoundation                          0x10e3d0810 -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 241
10  DevToolsCore                           0x128404af7 __52-[PBXTarget _adjustBuildSettingsForProductSettings:]_block_invoke + 809
11  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff816126967 __NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
12  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff816161bde -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 255
13  DevToolsCore                           0x128404739 -[PBXTarget _adjustBuildSettingsForProductSettings:] + 189
14  DevToolsCore                           0x1284050cc -[PBXTarget writeProductSettings:configuration:] + 348
15  DevToolsCore                           0x1284059a5 -[PBXTarget setProductSettings:configuration:] + 307
16  DevToolsCore                           0x128406f37 -[PBXTarget setProductSetting:forKey:configuration:] + 416
17  DevToolsCore                           0x12866fe7d -[Xcode3TargetInfoPlistCoordinator setValue:forPlistSetting:] + 158
18  Xcode3UI                               0x137cc92ee -[Xcode3TargetEditor setValue:forPlistSetting:] + 93
19  IDEiPhoneSupport                       0x137283fd2 -[IDEiOSTargetEditor setValue:forPlistSetting:withAssociatedBuildSetting:] + 207
20  Foundation                          0x7ff816f88c84 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 668
21  Foundation                          0x7ff816fb4172 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 68
22  Foundation                          0x7ff816fd1c47 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 269
23  Foundation                          0x7ff816f9420a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 353
24  AppKit                              0x7ff818ddc5e8 -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 445
25  AppKit                              0x7ff818ddc3dc -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 238
26  AppKit                              0x7ff819402f3e -[NSValueBinder _applyObjectValue:forBinding:canRecoverFromErrors:handleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:] + 215
27  AppKit                              0x7ff81940324d -[NSValueBinder applyDisplayedValueHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:canRecoverFromErrors:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 541
28  AppKit                              0x7ff8194033b4 -[NSValueBinder _applyDisplayedValueIfHasUncommittedChangesWithHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 106
29  AppKit                              0x7ff818f12ebd -[NSValueBinder validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 461
30  AppKit                              0x7ff818f12cc9 -[_NSBindingAdaptor _validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:bindingAdaptor:] + 175
31  AppKit                              0x7ff818f12bfa -[_NSBindingAdaptor validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 244
32  AppKit                              0x7ff818daf3e3 -[NSTextField textDidChange:] + 163
33  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff81615575c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
34  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8161f2b52 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 49
35  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8161f2ad0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 496
36  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff816127398 _CFXNotificationPost + 735
37  Foundation                          0x7ff816f6b80e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 82
38  AppKit                              0x7ff818daeec8 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) didChangeText] + 406
39  AppKit                              0x7ff818dac34b -[NSTextView _insertText:replacementRange:] + 2981
40  UIFoundation                        0x7ff819ac14fd -[NSTextContentManager performEditingTransactionUsingBlock:] + 39
41  AppKit                              0x7ff818dab789 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 112
42  AppKit                              0x7ff818dab283 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) insertText:replacementRange:completionHandler:] + 176
43  AppKit                              0x7ff819559e6e __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2.354 + 102
44  AppKit                              0x7ff818dab1c5 -[NSTextInputContext do_HandleTSMEvent_insertFixLenTextLoop:whileCondition:dispatchWorkEach:afterEachInsertText:continuation:] + 105
45  AppKit                              0x7ff818dab08c -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_insertFixLenText_withContext:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:nestedWorkaroundCondition:nestedWorkaroundDispatchWork:loopCondition:dispatchWorkEach:afterEachInsertText:continuation:] + 310
46  AppKit                              0x7ff819559568 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.310 + 2235
47  AppKit                              0x7ff818daacc8 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 74
48  AppKit                              0x7ff818daac49 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 87
49  AppKit                              0x7ff818daa24e -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 1821
50  AppKit                              0x7ff818da9ac0 _NSTSMEventHandler + 299
51  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81eddf34d DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1365
52  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81edde79c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 333
53  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81edde63d SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 45
54  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee397e3 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 442
55  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee39c53 __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 393
56  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee39aa5 __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 182
57  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee39831 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 520
58  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee395fc SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 219
59  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee392dd SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler + 274
60  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee39086 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 281
61  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee38ee6 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 362
62  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee38d4e TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 609
63  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee38ad2 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4 + 250
64  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee38951 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 257
65  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee3871d __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 285
66  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee384cd __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 274
67  HIToolbox                           0x7ff81ee2776a TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler + 3490
68  AppKit                              0x7ff81955d7e0 __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3.838 + 110
69  AppKit                              0x7ff81955d532 __204-[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:]_block_invoke.799 + 120
70  AppKit                              0x7ff818da858e -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:] + 245
71  AppKit                              0x7ff818da7f88 -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:] + 1422
72  AppKit                              0x7ff818da79bf -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:allowingSyntheticEvent:] + 105
73  AppKit                              0x7ff818da7836 -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 209
74  AppKit                              0x7ff818da767c -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 706
75  AppKit                              0x7ff818d101a6 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 7150
76  AppKit                              0x7ff818d0e39e -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 352
77  IDEKit                                 0x11172e1ba -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] + 156
78  AppKit                              0x7ff818d0d1c8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 2996
79  IDEKit                                 0x11176e92b -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 830
80  AppKit                              0x7ff818fc559b -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 65
81  AppKit                              0x7ff818b8df8e -[NSApplication run] + 623
82  DVTKit                                 0x10d5d5ea9 -[DVTApplication run] + 54
83  AppKit                              0x7ff818b61ee7 NSApplicationMain + 817
84  dyld
```